# how to make current user data provider using Riverpod that can handle latest update from Server?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am new in ***Riverpod*** state management, I am sorry if my question is very basic.

so I am confused how to make a current user data provider. say for example I have this `User` model

```
class User {
  final String uid;
  final String fullname;

  UserKM({
    required this.uid,
    required this.fullname,
  });

}
```

and let say I have two pages, `HomePage` and `ProfilePage`. the `ProfilePage` will be like the code below. just to show the user fullname using text by watching current user data provider

```
class ProfilePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context, watch) {

    final currentUser = watch(currentUserDataProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Text(currentUser.fullname),
    );
  }
}
```

and now imagine the home page has pull to refresh feature to get latest user data from server.

```
class HomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context, watch) {

    final homePageController = watch(homePageControllerNotifier);

    return Scaffold(
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () async => homePageController.getLatestDataFromServer(), // perform pull to refresh
        child: ,
    );
  }
}
```

and I have a HomePageController which is basically a change notifier like this

```
final homePageControllerNotifier = ChangeNotifierProvider<HomePageController>((ref) {
  return HomePageController();
});

class HomePageController with ChangeNotifier {


  Future<void> getLatestDataFromServer() async {

    // perform asynchronous operation using DB service .......
    // then successfully get user data from server

    final Map<String, dynamic> userData = dataFromServer;

    // then what should I do to this latest `userData` ???
    // to make latest update also displayed in ProfilePage that listen to current user Data Provider

  }
}
```

I am confused how to make `currentUserDataProvider` ( the provider that that will be watched / listened by `ProfilePage` ) , because I don't know how to put that latest userData from server to the `currentUserDataProvider` .

so if I change the fullname from server, then the user refresh the data by pull to refresh, I want to make the latest fullname will be displayed in `ProfilePage`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `ChangeNotifierProvider`, then you should use store the `userData` inside a var and update it with `notifyListeners();`

```
class HomePageController with ChangeNotifier {

  Map<String, dynamic> userData?;

  Future<void> getLatestDataFromServer() async {

    // perform asynchronous operation using DB service .......
    // then successfully get user data from server

    userData = dataFromServer;

    // then what should I do to this latest `userData` ???
    // to make latest update also displayed in ProfilePage that listen to current user Data Provider
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Then you can define your `currentUserDataProvider` like this:

```
final currentUserDataProvider = Provider<Map<String, dynamic>?>((ref) {
  final homePageController = ref.watch(homePageControllerNotifier);
  return homePageController.userData;
}
```

But whereas this works, I would recommend to use `StateNotifier` with a custom state class, which avoids to use `notifyListeners();` each time there is an update.